# What are the best design patterns, separations or structures which can be applied to ASP.NET MVC web applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I would like to know about the different types of desgin pattern/ structure/ speration can be used when developing asp.net mvc application. In this post I will summarize the tecnique used by me to further sperate asp.net application. I would like to know how to improve the current speration tecnique used in my projects. Further, I would like to know if there are any other desgin pattern/ structure or speration which can be applied when developing asp.net MVC applications. The level of speration recomnded to use is to keep the controller as clean as possbile from logical operation and data access layer. The architecture of my projects that I am working with is to call functions in the logical layer from controller. The logical layer classes do all logical operations than call functions in the data access layer. The data access layer then insert, update or return data. Also, I would like to find out if there are any other desgin pattern, sperations, or structure that I should apply to asp.net mvc projects. What are they, when to use them, when to use one over another and what are thier advtages. Further, should we always use desgin patterns, sperations, or structure to make functions reuseable even if these functions called once.

Comment: **This question is too broad.**  Narrow it down to a specific, software-related problem you are having.  Provide code samples to illustrate the problem.  Read [ask] for guidance.

Comment: If you need general guidance that addresses the concerns outlined in your question, from an authoritative source, you can find a wealth of it at https://asp.net/mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the gist of your question is which design pattern can be incorporated into the MVC application so that business logic can be separated from the controller actions. If that's the question, then I think the following answer will be sufficient for you.

The most common architecture followed in web application development is clean/ onion architecture. This architecture is developed with the help of repository patterns and dependency injection.

Every layer has its own responsibility to perform. There can be multiple different components. But most generally there are the following layers being used.

1. UI
2. Controller
3. Business Logic Layer
4. Database Access Layer
5. Database

The onion architecture provides higher flexibility and lesser coupling. I am attaching a GitHub repository link for a sample project. https://github.com/iammukeshm/OnionArchitecture

Answer (score 1):

Design designs are generally solutions for repetitive problems such as creating objects or changing structures, etc., which fall into three categories creational , structural and Behavioral Which each can solve a special problem
but principles are high level abstracts that are independent of projects or programming language for build and develop extensible and maintainable applications like solid, SOP, dry, kiss , etc.
I suggest you read more about design patterns and principles

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

> In software engineering, a software design pattern is a general,
> reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given
> context in software design.

https://www.laneways.agency/software-development-principles/

> What are the 10 Software Engineering Principles?